# css and Jquery loading problem in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, css, jquery

I install Magento 2.0 & also install a premium themes in Live. I am working with this theme. I finished my work & my website is ready for RUN.  Then I click the "flush Magento Catch" button. Then every thing is going to wrong. My website Css & Jquery is not loaded. Now what can I do? [image]
http://shulov.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run console command for generate static content (such as html, js, css file)

`magento setup:static-content:deploy`

*Documentation:*

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: I can't solve this problem till now. Please tell me some easy steps to solves this problem

Comment: I can't solve this problem till now. Please tell me some easy steps to solves this problem. My cPanel is not working also

Comment: you need to connect to your server using ssh and run static deploy command php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy